# Hibernate SQlite mapping class with iner classes exception The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I need to map object with an inner object which has one more inner object or inner array.

From this answer

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "zip_code":"0001",
   "user":{  
      "data":{  
         "id":1,
         "username":"user",
         "email":"user@gmail.com"
      }
   }
}
```

If I comment object field and left only zipCode and id all working fine.

StackOverflow says SQLite should have 1 open session
So I set hibernate.connection.pool_size to 1, and in this way it throws

```
Java/Hibernate - Exception: The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available
```

But it was yesterday. Today I again have "locked exception".
I think a problem in cascade. When hibernate try to save a first MainEntity it should save User, but DB already locked and in a result, it throws the exception. 
Even if I right I have no idea how to avoid it. I tried to use MERGE cascade type but it doesn't work in my situation.

Add project to a git repo 
https://github.com/JoaoMunozIII/hibernate

More info below.

After this sql queries

```
Hibernate: select mainentity_.mId, mainentity_.mZipCode as mZipCode2_0_ from main_entity mainentity_ where mainentity_.mId=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
```

I got this exception 
 [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

```
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: error performing isolated work
    at dialect.SQLiteDialect$3.convert(SQLiteDialect.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
    at DAO.saveEntityDb(DAO.java:16)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:155)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.commit(JDBC3Connection.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:60)
```

In the project. 
I create models:
Main Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntityModel {

    @Id
    private Long mId;

    private Long mZipCode;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User mUser;

    public Long getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setmId(Long mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public Long getmZipCode() {
        return mZipCode;
    }

    public void setmZipCode(Long mZipCode) {
        this.mZipCode = mZipCode;
    }

    public User getmUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public void setmUser(User mUser) {
        this.mUser = mUser;
    }
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_data")
public class User {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="mId")
    private UserEntity mData;

    public UserEntity getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setmData(UserEntity mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public User() {
    }
}
```

User entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_entity")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    private Long mId;

    private String mUsername;

    public Long getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setmId(Long mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public String getmUsername() {
        return mUsername;
    }

    public void setmUsername(String mUsername) {
        this.mUsername = mUsername;
    }
}
```

Hibernate Util

```
public class Hibernate {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static String dbPath = "D:" + File.separator + "temp.db";

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        System.out.println("factory " + sessionFactory);
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.sqlite.JDBC")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "dialect.SQLiteDialect")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath)
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "pass")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "pass")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "false")
                    .addAnnotatedClass(MainEntityModel.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(UserEntity.class);
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        } else {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

And Main class

```
public class Main {

    static Long userId = 1l;
    private static Long entityId = 1l;
    private static Long entityZip = 1000l;
    private static List<MainEntityModel> mainEntityModelList = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setmId(userId);
        userEntity.setmUsername("User Name " + userId++);

        User user = new User();
        user.setmData(userEntity);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            MainEntityModel mainEntityModel = new MainEntityModel();
            mainEntityModel.setmId(entityId++);
            mainEntityModel.setmUser(user);
            mainEntityModel.setmZipCode(entityZip++);
            mainEntityModelList.add(mainEntityModel);
        }

        DAO.saveEntityDb(mainEntityModelList);

        System.out.println("saved");

        List<MainEntityModel> savedList = DAO.getEntityDb();

        for (MainEntityModel entity: savedList) {
            System.out.println(entity.getmZipCode() + "\t"
                            + entity.getmUser().getData().getmUsername()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

DAO class

```
public class DAO {
    static final Session session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    public static void saveEntityDb(List<MainEntityModel> entityList){
        Transaction tx=null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for (MainEntityModel entity : entityList) {
                session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
            }
            session.flush();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        } finally{
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<MainEntityModel> getEntityDb(){
        Session session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<MainEntityModel> entityModel = session.createQuery("from MainEntityModel").list();
        session.close();
        return entityModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also my "data"  class just wrapper for an inner object. Should I save it or I can unwrap it in a someway? Now I just save it and generate ad in AUTO mode

Comment: Temporarily I save each internal class separately

Comment: add DAO.saveEntityDb() method please

Comment: @Zeromus added. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Problem: The auto generation of `user.id` - it mutually locks/concurs with the insert statement.
2. Problem: After the lock is fixed, we run into NPE's in the output loop

Solution:

1. Problem

   - Manually assign `user.id` and remove `@GeneratedValue()` annotation. (verified/tested)

     ```
     Main.java://or somewhere else
     ...
     user.setId(userId);
     ...


     User.java:
     ...
     @Id
     //!@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     ...
     ```

     - A nice alternative for "somewhere else" is:

       ```
       User.java:
       ...
       public void setmData(UserEntity mData) {
           this.mData = mData;
           if(mData == null) {
             this.id = null;
           } else {
             this.id = mData.getmId();
           }
       }

       @Id
       //!@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;
       ...
       ```
   - Or: Perist User/UserData in prior/separate transaction. ...like...

     - "improve" your DAO.java:

       ```
       public static <T extends Object> void saveEntityDb(T... entityList) {
         //local variable!
         final Session session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
         Transaction tx = null;
         try {
           if (session.isConnected()) {
             tx = session.beginTransaction();
             for (T entity : entityList) {
               session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
             }
             session.flush();
             tx.commit();
           }
         } catch (HibernateException ex) {
           if (tx != null && tx.getStatus().canRollback()) {
             tx.rollback();
           }
         } finally {
           if (session != null) {
             session.close();
           }
         }
       }
       ```
     - and use it twice(!):

       ```
       Main.java:
       ...
       User user = new User();
       user.setmData(userEntity);
       //do this before...
       DAO.saveEntityDb(user);

       List<MainEntityModel> mainEntityModelList = ...
       //...you do this
       DAO.saveEntityDb(mainEntityModelList.toArray(new MainEntityModel[0]));
       ```
2. Problem

   - get rid of the `insertable = false, updatable = false` on `MainEntityModel`'s `JoinColumn`.

...the `OneToOne` is somewhat strange here (@`MainEntityModel`) , it works, but rather used as a `ManyToOne` (5 to 1 ?!)

Comment: Thanks, @xerx593. It works without data. And you are right problem was with @GeneratedValue() 
But I can't avoid "data" wrapper. So I need save it with id. Maybe I can use embedded in some way. I do not have enough experience

Comment: the solution.. works "with data" and "with id"  ...but not auto generated AND  as a cascade persist in the same transaction... if you want 1 transaction, then you (obviously/unfortunately) cant auto-generate, and should assign id somehow useful (its a one-to-one!!!;) ...if you want the auto generation badly: then you would have to persist "user_data" in a prior transaction. (also verified& tested by now)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe you know some method to check is database locked to wait and to avoid exception?

Comment: the checking&waiting takes place (as jdbc/db feature) ...and ends up gracefully ...or with a timeout (u can configure with `connection.*` properties). In the given case waiting is useless/will never end, because the dead lock is (with)in your (single) transaction: you try to insert rows (which somehow locks) AND to generate the id (which also trys to lock/waits for lock until timeout). Sry, I am not deep into sqllite, neither in hibernate's sequence generation, but from my p.o.v. the locks are somewhat to "strict" (updating "hibernate_sequence" should not lock the (whole) table/db)

Comment: ....some ref: https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html , https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/